# Laravel Notifications Using Pusher

Tags: php, laravel-5, pusher

I am trying to make a Facebook like Notifications using pusher service with Laravel 5.3 and PHP 5.6.

Here are some steps I implemented.
.env file looks like

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=xxxxx
PUSHER_KEY=yyyyyyyyyyy
PUSHER_SECRET=zzzzzzzzz
```

My config/app.php :

```
'connections' => [

    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'ap2'
        ],
    ],
```

Then I created a event in app/Events :

```
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class PusherEvent implements ShouldBroadcast

{
use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */

public $user;
public function __construct($user)
{
      $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    //return new PrivateChannel('user.'.$this->user->id);
    return ['my_channel'];
}
}
```

and my app/providers/appserviceprovider look like :

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use App\Events\PusherEvent;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
         User::created(function ($user) {
            Event::fire(new PusherEvent($user));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

but it shows no event on dashboard console in pusher dashboard.

Comment: You might be able to get more information about where the problem is if you enable logging in the pusher library. You can find details of how to do that [here](https://pusher-community.github.io/real-time-laravel/getting-started/server-debugging.html)